# Expected string or bytes-like object in Selenium script

Tags: python-3.x

I am using Python 3.7.1 and getting the error

> expected string or bytes-like object

while running this script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import json
import os
import urllib.request
import argparse

searchterm = 'Empress Market' # will also be the name of the folder
url = "https://www.google.co.in/search?q="+searchterm+"&source=lnms&tbm=isch"
browser = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Tariq Ali/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
browser.get(url)
header={'User-Agent':"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.134 Safari/537.36"}
counter = 0
succounter = 0

if not os.path.exists(searchterm):
    os.mkdir(searchterm)

for _ in range(2):
    browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,10000)")

for x in browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"rg_meta")]'):
    counter = counter + 1
    print ("Total Count:", counter)
    print ("Succsessful Count:", succounter)
    print ("URL:",json.loads(x.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ou"])

    img = json.loads(x.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ou"]
    imgtype = json.loads(x.get_attribute('innerHTML'))["ity"]
    try:
        req = urllib.request.Request(img, headers={'User-Agent': header})
        raw_img = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
        File = open(os.path.join(searchterm , searchterm + "_" + str(counter) + "." + imgtype), "wb")
        File.write(raw_img)
        File.close()
        succounter = succounter + 1

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
           # logger.exception(e)

print (succounter, "pictures succesfully downloaded")
browser.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with these two lines:

```
req = urllib.request.Request(img, headers={'User-Agent': header})
raw_img = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
```

Change them to:

```
raw_img = urllib.request.urlopen(img).read()
```

Hope this helps.